# On their side idiomatic

Tags: word-usage

Is "on their side" idiomatic? Or do you use a similar expression or an idiom?

"If my friends needed me I was always on their side."

Comment: It's idiomatic, but it may not mean what you think it means from that example sentence. Please clarify.

Comment: @gone fishin' again I was always there ready to help them. I was the person they could turn to.

Comment: Being 'on someone's side' usually means 'taking their side in a dispute, argument, or difference of opinion'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, then it's wrong in my sentence. What would a native speaker use?

Comment: To be on someone's side does not mean you are 'always there for them' it means in an argument you take the same stance as they do. One may lead to the other, but they are not equivalents.

Comment: Many people would say, informally, "If my friends needed me I was always _there for them_", or more formally, "If my friends needed me I was always ready to help".

Comment: You might also be thinking of being "by someone's side," which is kind of a mix between being physically near someone and figuratively being "near" that person in the sense of being someone they can turn to. The usage patterns are free enough with the expression that it can be taken to mean exclusively the latter. I also feel like "on their side" wouldn't be completely unfamiliar in this sense, although the comments above me seem to think otherwise.